# Piping to stdout

Tags: c, pipe, stdout

Edit: Do not try connecting the end of a pipe to stdout. Connect the input of a pipe to stdout, and the output of the pipe to stdin.

I want to pipe the stdout of a child process to the stdout of its mother using pipe() and dup2(). 
In my example, I try and print a string in the child, which has its stdout redirect to the pipe; and then have the string appear in the stdout of the Mother. However, the output never appears in the stdout of the mother process. What is going on?

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
        // This program should print 1, 2 and 4; but only prints 1 and 4.

        int stdout_cpy = dup(1);

        printf("1. stdout working\n");

        int pipe1[2];
        pipe(pipe1);

        int pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
                // child
                dup2(pipe1[1], 1); // stdout out to pipe in
                close(pipe1[0]);
                fprintf(stdout, "2. This should print in the mother's stdout\n");
                exit(0);
        } else {
                // mother
                close(pipe1[1]);
                dup2(pipe1[0], 1); // stdout from pipe out
        }

        /* 2. should print in parent's stdout... */
        int status;
        while (wait(&status) > 0);

        printf("3. This should not print\n");

        dup2(stdout_cpy, 1);
        close(pipe1[0]);

        printf("4. stdout redirected, done\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1. stdout working
4. stdout redirected, done
```

Comment: Why are you calling `pipe` twice? Do you mean to call `fork` the second time?

Comment: In the parent process, `dup2(pipe1[0], 1)` is wrong. `pipe1[0]` is the *read* end of the pipe, why would you copy that to a *write* descriptor? What you're doing isn't correct in general. The child writes to standard output, and in the parent process you need to read that output from the read-end of the pipe. You can't really write directly to the parent process standard output descriptor from the child. Not like that anyway.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object while it is indeterminate.

Comment: I want the child to directly write to the stdout of the parent. I wasn't aware that was undefined behaviour. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The correct way to do it is not to use the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: I looked at what I posted and noticed the mistakes you were talking about. I had intended this to be a simple example of something else I was working on, but I made a number of mistakes when writing my example. Please review my update.

Comment: By default, the standard output of the child will go to the same place as the standard output of the parent — so you're doing a lot of extra work for no obvious benefit.  What's the real requirement?  That the parent read the standard output of the child?

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: And since you don't initialize `stdout_cpy`, the code `int stdout_cpy;
        dup2(1, stdout_cpy);` could fail easily — but you don't check.  In context, you could use `int stdout_cpy = dup(1);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In my full program, the child calls exec, I should have added exit in my example and I have updated it to include this. I want to redirect stdout because my original program chains many exec calls together in a few pipes before writing to the parents stdout (the part I am having trouble with).  Thank you for the observation about stdout_cpy, I have fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code.  For the output from the child to appear, the parent must read it from the pipe and then write that to its own standard output, which is what this code does.  If nothing reads from the pipe, the output written to the pipe won't appear anywhere.  This change makes the duplicated standard output basically irrelevant.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{   
    int stdout_cpy = dup(1);            // Mostly irrelevant

    printf("1. stdout working\n");

    int pipe1[2];
    pipe(pipe1);

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child at work
        dup2(pipe1[1], 1);              // stdout out to write end of pipe
        close(pipe1[0]);                // Close both ends of the pipe!
        close(pipe1[1]);                // Close both ends of the pipe!
        printf("2. This should be read by parent from stdin and be printed to the parent's stdout\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Parent at work */
    dup2(pipe1[0], 0);                  // stdin from from read end of pipe
    close(pipe1[0]);                    // Close both ends of the pipe!
    close(pipe1[1]);                    // Close both ends of the pipe!

    // Read data written on pipe by child, and write to stdout
    char buffer[512];
    int nbytes = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (nbytes > 0)
        write(1, buffer, nbytes);

    /* 2. should print in parent's stdout... */
    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);

    printf("3. This should print too\n");

    dup2(stdout_cpy, 1);                // Mostly irrelevant
    //close(pipe1[0]);                  // Long since closed
    close(stdout_cpy);                  // No longer needed (closed on exit anyway)

    printf("4. stdout redirected, done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
1. stdout working
2. This should be read by parent from stdin and be printed to the parent's stdout
8008: child 8009 exited with status 0x0000
3. This should print too
4. stdout redirected, done
```

Alternatively, if you just want the child's output to appear on the same device as the parent's output, simply don't use a pipe at all; the child will inherit the parent's standard output and can write to it without any extra help.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see my error was assuming that I could connect the output of the pipe to stdout directly. I have made some adjustments to my work following your inheritance suggestion and it now works exactly as I had wanted. Thanks for the help.